# How do I properly form my tpl for the BreadCrumb snippet in MODx Revolution?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am transitioning from the Breadcrumbs snippet to the BreadCrumb snippet.

This is my Breadcrumbs code:

```
[[Breadcrumbs? &respectHidemenu=`0` &crumbSeparator=`` currentAsLink=`false` &showHomeCrumb=`0` &titleField=`bc-title`]]
```

This is my BreadCrumb code:

```
[[BreadCrumb? showHidden=`0` showBreadCrumbAtHome=`0`]]
```

I am trying to mimic the titleField portion from Breadcrumbs in my BreadCrumbLinkCrumbTpl and my BreadCrumbCurrentCrumbTpl using (so if bc-title is empty, rollback to pagetitle):

```
<li><a href="[[+link]]">[[*bc-title:empty=`[[+pagetitle]]`]]</a></li>
```

It works great on BreadCrumbCurrentCrumbTpl, but on BreadCrumbLinkCrumbTpl it is only showing pagetitle, not bc-title first. It's almost like it can't traverse? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Breadbrumbs does not have any settings for including template-variables (which sucks). You could do a simple workaround like this:

```
<li><a href="[[+link]]">[[!parseNavTitle? &sid=`[[+id]]`]]</a></li>
```

The snippet `parseNavTitle`:

```
$obj = $modx->getObject('modResource',$sid);
if ($obj->getTVValue('bc-title') == '')
    return $obj->get('pagetitle');
else
    return $obj->getTVValue('bc-title');
```

Comment: Thanks OptimusCrime :) I ended up just using QuickCrumbs, it supports custom Template Variables